# Git not getting files

Tags: git, github

I am setting example project in github 
then in my local machine I created a folder "mytest" then I cloned the project in github. and I initialized the folder by issuing the git init. after that I createad 3 html pages and issuing the command.

```
git add file1.html
git commit -m  "test saving to master repo"
git push origin/master
```

then when I looked at to my github account it's successfully pushed,
now I deleted the 3 files in local machine. and I used this command to 
get all the files or updated files in my github.

```
git fetch origin/master
```

or

```
git pull origin/master
```

but it did not getting files.

how can i get the files in github what command should I used ?

Comment: Use `git fetch` (as you did), followed by `git checkout master`.  Look here for more info: http://git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout.  Plan B (not recommended except as a "last resort") is `git fetch origin && git reset --hard origin/master && git clean -f -d`.  Replace "origin" and "master" with the remote and branch that you want to synchronize with

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The files did not change, so they are not fetched but your local changes are preserved.

To get the commited copy from your master branch, use

```
git checkout master -- <files>
```

Comment: but how to get all of files from master which is not present in my local ?

Comment: I mean if someone added new files  how can I get the newly added files how do I know if that file is am I going to fetch?

Comment: That is a `git pull`.

Comment: I tried to use use "git pull" but it return "already up-to-date".

Comment: Then the files may be up to date. Did you push the other commit, does it show up in the logs?

Comment: I see now the logs, how do I get back or quit so that i can type command again ?

Comment: That probably depends on your `$PAGER` i assume. Try standard `less` keys.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to previous answer if you want to reset *all* your files to the repository version discarding all not staged changes you can use

```
get reset --hard  HEAD
```

So you don't need to specify file list